# Is the "publish..." action in VS2008 automatically compile in "release" mode?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I'm a bit confused about all that

- Does `<compilation debug="true">` in web.config mean that you are in Debug mode? I guess no? Is this related to debug/release mode?
- Is the "publish..." action in VS2008 automatically compile in "release" mode? Where can I bind  "publish..." action to "release" mode?
- When I "publish..." a project and if I have `<compilation debug="true">`, does the compiler insert all of the extra code for debugging?

I guess this is simple but it seems confusing for me

David

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<compilation debug="true">` refers to run-time page compilation mode, and is not related to your build configuration. It does not affect your project's primary assembly, or supporting libraries; just pages.

`Publish...` will publish assemblies and content using the current build configuration, be it Debug, Release, or some other custom configuration.

If you are using Visual Studio 2010, you can look at web.config transforms to ensure you do not release code with the compilation debug flag set to true. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx

Comment: Beat me to it. I was just double checking some facts about `<compilation debug="true">` here - http://aspalliance.com/1341

Comment: @ChrisF: Thanks for the additional info!